# Find the inverse of $2^{10}$ modulo $2011$ and compute $2^{2000} \pmod{2011}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Find the inverse of $2^{10}$ modulo $2011$ and then compute the remainder of the division of $2^{2000}$ by $2011$.

I managed to find the inverse, it was simple, I just had to solve the diophantine equation $1024x+2011k = 1$. I did this by applying the extended euclidean algorithm, and found that the inverse $s$ is $s=83$. But I'm not sure how to apply it to solve $2^{2000}\pmod{2011}$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: By Fermat $\,2^{\color{#c00}{2010}}\equiv 1\,$ so $\bmod \color{#c00}{2010}\!:\ \color{#0a0}{2000\equiv -10}\,\Rightarrow\,  2^{\color{#0a0}{2000}}\equiv 2^{\color{#0a0}{-10}}\,$ by [mod order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242) in linked dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, you know that $$2^{\varphi(2011)}\equiv 1\; \bmod 2011$$ but $$\varphi(2011)=2010=10+2000$$ then you can use this, and obtain $$2^{10}*2^{2000} = 1 \;\bmod 2011$$ then you have the answer

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).